# How to replace question marks inside a string with the values of an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, underscore.js

Given the string `'Hello ?, welcome to ?'` and the array `['foo', 'bar']`, how do I get the string `'Hello foo, welcome to bar'` in a single line of code with JavaScript (possibly with jQuery, Underscore, etc.)?

Comment: Do they have to be question marks?

Comment: Why does it have to be a single line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var s = 'Hello ?, welcome to ?';
var a = ['foo', 'bar'];
var i = 0;
alert(s.replace(/\?/g,function(){return a[i++]}));
```

Comment: +1 You could also eliminate `i` by using `return a.shift()` (though `a` would be empty afterwards).

Comment: @Andrew almost anything can take a function.

Answer (score 7):

Kind of silly to put it all on one line, but:

```
var str = 'Hello ?, welcome to ?',
    arr = ['foo', 'bar'],
    i = 0;


while(str.indexOf("?") >= 0) { str = str.replace("?", arr[i++]); }
```

Comment: Would be more beautiful if you sis str = str.replace("?", arr[i++]);

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking that myself.. Updating... And thanks for the comment!

Comment: This has to be the most dubious JS comma placing style I have ever seen.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [vsprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).  Although if you include sprintf, it's much more than one line.

```
vsprintf('Hello %s, welcome to %s', [foo, bar]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let str = 'Hello ?, welcome to ?'
let arr = ['foo', 'bar']
const fn = Array.prototype.shift.bind(arr)
let  result = str.replace(/\?/g, fn)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's build a `replaceWith` function:

```js
const replaceWith =
  (...str) =>
    (fallback) =>
      str.length === 0
        ? fallback
        : str.shift();
```

It's a curried function: it takes a list of replacement strings and returns another function which will return the replacements one by one:

```js
const replacements = replaceWith('', '', '');
replacements(); //=> ''
replacements(); //=> ''
replacements(); //=> ''
```

After the third call you have exhausted all the replacements so the next calls will either return `undefined` or whatever you passed as a `fallback` parameter:

```js
replacements(); //=> undefined
replacements(''); //=> ''
```

This `fallback` parameter can be handy if you have more substrings to replace than replacement strings at your disposal. (But we will come to that later.)

Now using `replaceWith` we can do:

```js
'Hello ?, welcome to ?'.replace(/\?/g, replaceWith('foo', 'bar'));
//=> 'Hello foo, welcome to bar'
```

Behind the scene it calls the function returned by `replaceWith` (let's call it `fn`) with:

```js
fn('?'); //=> 'foo'
fn('?'); //=> 'bar'
```

The `fallback` parameter (i.e. your placeholder `'?'` in this case) is ignored while there are still replacement strings. However it will be returned as is when there are more placeholders than replacements:

```js
'Hello ? and ?, welcome to ?'.replace(/\?/g, replaceWith('foo', 'bar'));
//=> 'Hello foo and bar, welcome to ?'
```

---

**Acknowledgment**

This answer is a variation of [Alex Varghese excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269898/1244884).